# Implementing Pipes in a C shell (Unix)

Tags: c, unix, shell, pipe

Basically I have created a shell using standard POSIX commands, I want to be able to Implement Piping as well. Right now it handles commands correctly, and can do background processing with &. But I need to be able to pipe using | and >> as well.
For example something like this:
cat file1 file2 >> file3
cat file1 file2 | more
more file1 | grep stuff

Here is the code I have currently. I also want to AVOID "SYSTEM" calls. I know U need to use dup2, but the way I did my code is a bit odd, so im hoping if someone can tell me if it is feasible to implement pipes in this code? thanks! I know dup2 is used, but also im def. confused at how to implement >> as WELL as |

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


void Execute(char* command[],bool BG)
{
//Int Status is Used Purely for the waitpid, fork() is set up like normal.
    int status;
    pid_t pid = fork();


    switch(pid)
    {
        case  0:
            execvp(command[0], command);

            if(execvp(command[0], command) == -1)
            {
                cout << "Command Not Found" << endl;
                exit(0);
            }

          default:
            if(BG == 0)
            {
                    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
//Debug             cout << "DEBUG:Child Finished" << endl;
            }


    }

}


bool ParseArg(char* prompt, char* command[], char Readin[],bool BG)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "myshell>");
        cin.getline(Readin,50);
    prompt = strtok(Readin, " ");
    int i = 0;

    while(prompt != NULL)
    {
        command[i] = prompt;
        if(strcmp(command[i], "&") == 0){
//Debug        cout << "& found";
        command[i] = NULL;
        return true;
    }
//Debug        cout << command[i] << " ";
        i++;
        prompt = strtok(NULL, " ");

    }
    return false;
}

void Clean(char* command[])
{
//Clean Array
        for(int a=0; a < 50; a++)
        {
             command[a] = NULL;
        }
}



int main()
{
   char* prompt;
   char* command[50];
   char Readin[50]; 
   bool BG = false;



   while(command[0] != NULL)
   {

        Clean(command);
       BG = ParseArg(prompt, command, Readin, BG);
       if(strcmp(command[0], "exit") == 0 || strcmp(command[0], "quit") == 0 )
       {
             break;
       }

    else
    {
            Execute(command,BG);
    }

   }

   return 1;

}
```

Comment: Why were you trying to avoid system calls?  Portability?  You may stick with the POSIX specified system calls as much as possible.  Also, your shell is a strange mix of C and C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to implement pipes and output redirection with your shell, but there are a few things I noticed:

- Your code for reading input, parsing, and output are mixed together, you may want to separate this functionality.
- strtok won't work very well as a parser for shell commands. It will work for very simple   commands, but you may want to look into creating or finding a better parser. A command like `echo "hello world"` will be problematic with your current parsing method.
- You may want to create a simple structure for holding your parsed commands.

Here is some pseudocode to get you started:

```
#define MAX_LINE 10000
#define MAX_COMMANDS 100
#define MAX_ARGS 100

// Struct to contain parsed input
struct command
{
    // Change these with IO redirection
    FILE *input; // Should default to STDIN
    FILE *output; // Should default to STDOUT

    int num_commands;
    int num_args[MAX_COMMANDS]; // Number of args for each command
    char* command_list[MAX_COMMANDS]; // Contains the programs to be run
    char* args_list[MAX_COMMANDS][MAX_ARGS]; // The args for each command
    boolean background_task;
    boolean append;
}

int main()
{
    char input[MAX_LINE];

    while (1)
    {
        struct command cmd;

        print_prompt();
        read_input(input);
        parse_input(input, &cmd);
        execute(&cmd);
    }
}
```

Good luck with this project!

Answer (score 6):

Pipes and redirections are different, actually. To implement a redirection (such as `>>`) you have to use `dup2` indeed. First, open the desired file with appropriate flags (for `>>` they'll be `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND`). Second, using `dup2`, make stdout (file descriptor 1) a copy of this newly opened fd. Finally, close newly opened fd.

To create a pipe, you'll need a `pipe` syscall. Read its manpage, it contains example code. Then you'll also need `dup2` to make file descriptors returned by `pipe` be stdin for one process and stdout for another, respectively.

Comment: DO you think with the way I did my shell it will be "possible" or should I redesign my shell?