# Using pipe in bash-style shell

Tags: c, shell, unix, communication, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing Pipes in a C shell (Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930339/implementing-pipes-in-a-c-shell-unix)

Hi,

I'm writing a minishell to understand how Bash works and I want it to use pipe like
`ls | sort` for example (all commands using `>`, `<` , `>>`, `&` works fine)

Here is the structure :

```
main() {
display loop {
   -> function that use strtok to split command line and store commands
   -> fork
parent process : make a wait()
child process has the execution loop with execv.
}
```

I've got some problem to understand how to implement pipe.

I create something like `fd[2]` to use the pipe : `fd[0]` to read, `fd[1]` to write.

I know that I use `pipe()` function in parent process. When I `fork()`, the child process inherits of `fd[2]`.
In my minishell, only the child process can execute a command.

I'm a little confused because I don't know if I have to use `fork()` two times ? and who (parent or child) executes a command, I want to keep just one execution loop (like I explain previously). Do you think it's a good idea to use read and write ?

`ls | sort` : output `ls` has to be written in pipe, then the process has to read the pipe and this becomes the input of the `sort` command, am I right ?

thanks :-)

edit : I would use just one exec, I don't know if it's possible ?

Comment: Might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101506/how-does-shell-execute-piped-commands/5101657#5101657

Comment: @Brian: Although the question appears the same topically, the root issue was actually quiet different in that question. The answer does not necessarily reflect what is being asked here.